# python swap and assignment

Tags: python, swap

Usually, we use `A[i], A[j] = A[j], A[i]` to swap.

This may not work sometimes. For example,

```
A=[1, 2]
A[0], A[A[0]] = A[A[0]], A[0]
```

will fail. Why does it fail and how is the assignment interpreted?

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at the bytecode for the statement in question:

```
>>> def f(A):
...   A[0], A[A[0]] = A[A[0]], A[0]
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
            3 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
            6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
            9 BINARY_SUBSCR
           10 BINARY_SUBSCR
           11 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
           14 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
           17 BINARY_SUBSCR
           18 ROT_TWO
           19 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
           22 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
           25 STORE_SUBSCR
           26 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
           29 LOAD_FAST                0 (A)
           32 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
           35 BINARY_SUBSCR
           36 STORE_SUBSCR
           37 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           40 RETURN_VALUE
```

This works like this:

- Instructions 0-10 push A[A[0]] on the value stack, so it is `2`
- Instructions 11-17 push A[0] on the value stack, now it is `2, 1`
- Instruction 18 swaps them, the stack is `1, 2`
- Instructions 19-25 assigns the top value (2) to A[0], leaving the value stack as `1`
- Instructions 26-36 try to assign a value to A[A[0]], but A[0] is now 2, so it's trying to assign to A[2], which is an IndexError.

In short, the problem is that `A[A[0]]` on the left-hand side isn't evaluated until after the assignment to `A[0]`.

As a fix, I suggest:

```
A0 = A[0]
A[0], A[A0] = A[A0], A[0]
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why the former statement works, and the latter doesn't.

Comment: @popovitsj I added a sentence or two.

Comment: `A0, A[0], A[A0] = A[0], A[A[0]], A[0]` or `A0, A[0], A[A0] = A[0], A[A[0]], A0` also work.

Comment: Thanks! So a tmp variable is needed when the index is a mutable object.